# Declaring of maven dependency check as plugin vs dependency

Tags: spring-boot, pom.xml, maven-plugin

what is the difference between declaring the maven dependency check plugin as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
    <version>${dependency-check-maven.version}</version>
    <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
    <version>${dependency-check-maven.version}</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: 1st uses it "as a dependency" (for what!??) 2nd uses it as plugin (as documented)

Comment: but besides "using it as dependency", if i (quickly) would like to investigate the javadoc/sources (with my IDE), i *would* do first (temporarily..not for release!;)

Comment: I was wondering whether the type "maven-plugin" could be an equivalent of declaring it as a plugin.

Comment: The `type` of dependency refers to the `packaging` of that (referred/depended) artifact (jar would be the default...omitting that: could raise you an "artifact resolution exception", but could also (gracefully) fallback (to jar/the available artifact ..please try!;)

Comment: ok, then naively I would guess that declaring a dependency with type "maven-plugin" is roughly equivalent of adding a maven plugin? :)   or rather adding a plugin and not using it as a plugin but rather to use its classes?

Comment: Exactly: in both cases maven uses/downloads the same "jar": but the 1st (`<dependency/>`) does nothing (active...until you use it "at runtime"), whereas the 2nd affects your maven build.